# unable to mount volume to spark.kubernetes.executor

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kubernetes, server, data-science

I am trying to read a file from server in spark cluster mode using kubernetes, so i put my file on all workers and i mount driver volume using
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("sparksetuptest")
.set("spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.hostPath.host.mount.path", "/file-directory")

Everything works fine here but when i execute it shows that file not found at specific location.
So i mount directory to executor with .set("spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.hostPath.host.mount.path", "/file-directory")
But now i am not able to execute program it stuck in a never ending process while fetching data.

Please suggest something, so that i can mount my directory with executor and read that file.

Comment: Could you solve this ? I am interested in your solution.

Answer (score 3):

this is an example from [nfs-example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/docs/running-on-kubernetes.md)

```
spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.nfs.images.options.server=example.com
spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.nfs.images.options.path=/data
```

I think you need to declare the path that you want to mount under `options.path` and the `spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.[VolumeType].[VolumeName].mount.path` is the mount path in your container

For example:

If I want to mount `/home/lemon/data` on the node of k8s to the path `/data` the docker container with VolumeName `exepv`, then

```py
conf.set("spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.hostPath.exepv.mount.path","/data")
conf.set("spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.hostPath.exepv.options.path", "/home/lemon/data")
```

after this, you can access the path `/data` in your executor container

Comment: I did exactly what you said. Yet, I got the same problem still. I went into my running container and went straight to the mountPath and did an ls and found no files ...